# Is cloud based load testing deprecated?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

Came across an article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/ which says that cloud-based load testing service has been deprecated.

in this article, at one point it says that,

> "Running a load test in the cloud using Visual Studio (both
>   auto-provisioned agents and self-provisioned ‘bring-your-own’ agents):
>   You can continue to run the tests but self-hosted with Test
>   Controller/Test Agent option outlined above."

If all my load testing agents, controllers are created as VMs in Azure - and I use my VSTS subscription to run these load tests then do I need to worry? The above paragraph is a little confusing, hence asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Customer support questions are generally off-topic here, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions .

Comment: See also See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f38aaca5-4e31-473b-9a86-2f5c3df3e12a/web-performance-and-load-test-functionality-is-deprecated-visual-studio-2019-is-the-last-version?forum=vstest where this topic has been discussed in detail.